# Redefine \prime with unicode-math

Tags: math-mode, unicode-math, accents

I'm using `unicode-math` (with XeLaTeX) to set my text and math fonts. However, using `Garamond-math` as a math font, I see the `\prime` symbol is too close to the letter:

[image]

I am trying to redefine the `\prime` command, and if possible I would like to remap `'` in math mode so that it gives the correct spacing. However, the "usual" solution to redefine `\prime`, that is (MWE)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Garamond-Math.otf}[StylisticSet={5,7,9}]
\let\originalprime\prime
\def\prime{\mkern3mu\originalprime\mkern-3}
\begin{document}

$f'(x)$

\end{document}
```

but this solution does not seem to work in this context. I also tried

```
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\AtBeginDocument{\newunicodechar{′}{\mkern3mu\prime\mkern-3u}}
```

but again it had no effect.

Comment: As always you are more likely to get help if you provide full but minimal examples, not these sniplets, but something others can copy and test as is.

Comment: It is most likely not the prime that is the main problem, but the italic f and its bounding box. In ConTeXt we can fix this on the fly, compare [without fix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XcB0x.png) and [with fix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cz3Kk.png).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `unicode-math` the command `\prime` is defined in terms of an internal function, which is used when `f'(x)` is processed. So redefining `\prime` does nothing, unless you *do* use it explicitly.

There is no interface for modifying the behavior, unfortunately. But the following works with the current version of `unicode-math`. However, due to accessing private functions, this is not guaranteed to remain stable in future releases.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Garamond-Math.otf}[StylisticSet={5,7,9}]

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set:Npn \__um_prime_single_mchar { \mkern2mu\Umathchar"0"0"2032\mkern-2mu~}
\cs_set:Npn \__um_prime_double_mchar { \mkern2mu\Umathchar"0"0"2033\mkern-2mu~}
\cs_set:Npn \__um_prime_triple_mchar { \mkern2mu\Umathchar"0"0"2034\mkern-2mu~}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$f'(x)+f''(x)+f'''(x)$

$g'(x)+g''(x)+g'''(x)$

$h'(x)+h''(x)+h'''(x)$

\end{document}
```

[image]